# JFace Databinding Map Property to SWT Text Field

Tags: java, dictionary, data-binding, swt, jface

I'm trying to bind a map property to a simple SWT Text widget.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
value = new WritableValue();
WritableMap map = new WritableMap();
map.put("test", "test");
value.setValue(map);

IObservableValue target = WidgetProperties.text().observe(part.getTxt());
IObservableValue model = BeanProperties.value("test").observeDetail(value); 
dbc.bindValue(target, model);
```

This does indeed not work. If I use `BeanProperties.map(...)` then it returns an `IObservableMap` which I can't use at `dbc.bindValue(...)`.

I would be very happy if someone could explain how to do it correctly.

Comment: A Map has multiple values, what should the be shown in the Text widget?

Comment: the value of the key i want to specify like in the (not working) example... I want to bind several keys of the map to each a textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find the right way (TM), you might as well write your own `IObservableValue`, it's not that hard:

```
public class MapObservableValue extends AbstractObservableValue {

private final Map map;

public MapObservableValue(Map map) {
    this.map = map;
}

@Override
public Object getValueType() {
    return Object.class;
}

@Override
protected Object doGetValue() {
    return map.get("test");
}

@Override
protected void doSetValue(Object value) {
    map.put("test", value);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, ok thats another solution. So nobody seems to have a clue how to make it via the databinding api I will accept you answer cause its also suitable for my case ! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Finally found it... map entries can be observed via

```
IObservableValue o = Observables.observeMapEntry(map, "test")
```